# How to find string in a range them sum results from a different worksheet - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to avoid using vba if I can but if it is the only solution I will.  I have a range of cells containing different departments and I want to search through them and find only the options that contain "SE" in them.  Then SUMIFS only those values from another page. I'm using office 2013

Worksheet 1

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Green | Blue | Red | GreenSE |

Worksheet 2

| Dept | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| Green | 5 |
| GreenSE | 10 |
| Blue | 2 |
| BlueSE | 3 |
| Red | 5 |
| RedSE | 6 |
| Green | 8 |
| GreenSE | 3 |

I want to find all options in worksheet 1 that contain SE (This list changes).  Then SUM the corresponding values from worksheet 2.

| E | F |
| --- | --- |
| SE's from List | 13 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Office 365 and later we can use FILTER inside a SUMIFS:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(N:N,M:M,FILTER(A1:D1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SE",A1:D1)))))
```

[image]

Or as JVDV showed we can skip the SUMIFS with COUNTIFS inside the FILTER:

```
=SUM(FILTER(N2:N9,COUNTIFS(A1:D1,M2:M9,A1:D1,"*SE")))
```

---

With all versions:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(N2:N9,M2:M9,"*SE",M2:M9,A1:D1))
```

[image]

Comment: I should have pointed out im on Office 2013

Comment: Oh god, I was definitely approaching it way too complicated, seeing your sumproduct solution.

Comment: @P.b I got anchored by FILTER.  The SUMPRODUCT/SUMIFS is definitely easier regardless of version.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using `SUMPRODUCT` over `SUM`? (Array functionality by default maybe?)

Comment: @P.b Correct, for older versions that do not have the dynamic array functionality, SUMPRODUCT version will not require the Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Answer (score 1):

In older Excel it's quite hard to get what you want, but it's possible:

```
=(SUM(
  IFERROR(
    INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$9,
          AGGREGATE(15,6,
             ROW(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$9)-1
             /MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(
                    INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$D$1,
                          AGGREGATE(15,6,                    
                             COLUMN(Sheet1!$A$1:$D$1)
                             /COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A$1:$D$1,Sheet1!$A$1:$D$1,Sheet1!$A$1:$D$1,"*SE*"),                         
                          ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A$1:$D$1,"*SE*"))))))=Sheet2!$A$2:$A$9), 
             ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A$1:$D$1,"*SE*")))^0),
    ROW(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$9)-1)),
  0)))
```

The `MMULT` part filters the values containing `SE` (note this can also be in the middle or start of the value).
It retrieves the row numbers of the values in `Sheet2!A2:A9` that equal any of the filtered values. And this is used in the outer `INDEX` to get the values in column B summed.

Comment: Or just use the Sumproduct solution Scott Craner added in his post, lol.